# What is a more efficient way to choose/sort the best node in an A* search?

Tags: python, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am using an A* search and a Breadth First search to find a winning game state in an 8 puzzle.  The winning state looks like this

```
123
456
780
```

and stored as a list like such

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I used a heuristic function to score each node (based on its state), but I believe my method of prioritizing the best scored nodes is slowing my program down a lot.  So much so actually that the breadth first search algorithm I made vastly outperforms the A* algorithm (even though most of the the inner workings are identical).

I believe the main thing slowing my A* search down is that I'm using the position in the fringe (the list holding my nodes) to indicate the next node to prioritize.

```
def aStartSort(node):
    if not fringe:
        fringe.append(node)
    else:
        fl = len(fringe)
        if node.score >= fringe[fl-1].score:
            fringe.append(node)
        else:
            for i in range(fl):
                if node.score < fringe[i].score:
                    fringe.insert(i, node)
```

So as you can see, every time a node is added to the fringe, it looks for a node that is scored worse than it, and then inserts itself in front of it.  This ensures that I get a least a tie for the best scored node when I do fringe.pop(0).  But inserting items into the middle of a giant list isn't a very fast action is it?  What would be a better alternative?

I also considered not ordering the fringe list, but that seems just as bad or worse (because the entire list would have to be searched each time a node is popped out.

Comment: Maybe one way to do it would be to look at the 'path' to the solution your BFS finds, and then look at where your A* is deviating from that 'known best' path.

Comment: @TomDalton Well the I don't have a choice on the heuristic I'm using to score the nodes, so I don't really get to change the path of the A*.  The heuristic is the amount of tiles that are misplaced (so a max of 8) and the cost is 1 per move.  So the full score is decided by f(n) = misplaced tiles + depth.  

Other than that, the algorithms are pretty much identical. So all I'm left with is looking for a faster way of sorting through the nodes I do pick.

Comment: If the scores are ranging 0-8, then you could keep a `dict` of score:nodes, which would save you doing the scan through the big list looking for the insert point - you just add the new node to the end of the list in the relevant dict key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, assuming your scores are integers, create a dictionary of lists, mapping scores to nodes with that score. That makes inserts O(1), and since you can iterate over the possible score range, retrieval should be fast as well.